# Power BI OData feed doesn't works with +15.000 records

Tags: web-services, powerbi, odata, dynamics-business-central, odata-v4

I want to use Power BI to retrieve an ODATA feed from a Microsoft Business Central database. This Webservice is a page with 15,000 rows and per row 75 fields.

A previous ODATA feed with the same amount did work. Unfortunately with this one it fails to quickly retrieve all the data.

I am using the following OData V4 Feed:

```
https://navserver.cronus.com7148/cronus-live-BC140_WS/ODataV4/Company('CRONUS')/Campaign
```

Can anyone help me how come I can't retrieve data?

Outcome of the OData feed containing all 15000 records

Answer (score 0):

OData has many limitations if you use it as the connector for BC.
You can view the limitations here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/business-central/dev-itpro/api-reference/v2.0/dynamics-current-limits

I would strongly suggest using the Business Central connector. Think of it as a smart connector. It does the same as the OData one except it has an integration pagination that gets all the rows automatically.

For example, it will get the first 20K rows, the 20-40K rows, etc.

Since you only have 15K rows, you're probably hitting another limit.

You could also develop your extension that adds a custom API to your BC environment.
If you're not confortable coding for BC, you can buy an extension that can help you customize your environment. I was in the same boat and this helped me a lot: https://www.hougaard.com/designer/